# Spring Boot Value annotation inside HandlerInterceptorAdaper

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a HandlerInterceptorAdapter like

```
@Component
public class TestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

    @Value("${thing:defaultValue}")
    private String thing;

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse  response,
                             Object handler) throws Exception {

        // Do something with thing, but thing is null.

    }
}
```

Is it not possible to get config values injected into this class? What's going on here? I would have expected it to at least have the default value but it has nothing.

Comment: Only if it is a spring bean. If you construct it yourself, not in a `@Bean` method it is not a spring bean.

Comment: Ok, I see what I did wrong... Apparently it was being independently instantiated inside another Configuration class instead of being autowired in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that Spring is actually instantiating the Component :)

So, like

```
@Configuration
public class InterceptorConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    TestInterceptor test;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
        InterceptorRegistration testreg = registry.addInterceptor(test);
        // ...
    }
}
```

By Autowiring it in to the Configurer, it makes Spring aware of it.